# Finding length of centre of sphere to surface in 2D

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to automate drawing a cylinder that "attaches" to a sphere, but as a 2D drawing. I'm having a bit of difficulty making the image look 3D since I need to change the length of the cylinder so that it looks like it attaches to the outside of the sphere.
I drew out a diagram that will hopefully demonstrates my problem: [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0roU.png). The top view is only for clarity of what it would hypothetically look like in 3D, and to show that the cylinder that connects Point A and the Circle always points to the center of the Circle.

Known variables:

- X, Y, and Z coordinates of Point A and the Circle

  - The Z coordinate of Point A is always in front of the Circle (i.e. the cylinder is always drawn in front)
- Radius of the Circle
- Distance from Point A to the center of the Circle.

Since the cylinder always points to the center of the sphere, the easiest way I have thought of doing this is subtracting the length of r in the 2D view from the cylinder, but I have no idea how to find length r.

Is there any formula I can use to find the length r?

Thank you in advanced and hopefully my wording isn't too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the parameters $r>0,R>r,H>R$ and sampled the following *3D points*:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& (x_s,y_s,z_s) = (R\sin\phi\cos\theta,R\sin\phi\sin\theta,R\cos\phi), \quad \; \; (\phi,\theta) \in [0,\pi] \times [0,2\pi)\,; \\ 
& (x_c,y_c,z_c) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,t), \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \; \; (t,\theta) \in [R,H] \times [0,2\pi)\,; \\
& (x_p,y_p,z_p) = (\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta,H), \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \; \; \, (\rho,\theta) \in [0,r] \times [0,2\pi)\,; \\
\end{aligned}
$$

based on [this explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249408/32491), the respective *2D points* are obtained in the following way:

$$
\begin{cases}
x' = \cos(w)(y\cos(v)-x\sin(v))-\sin(w)[z\cos(u)-\sin(u)(x\cos(v)+y\sin(v))] \\
y' = \sin(w)(y\cos(v)-x\sin(v))+\cos(w)[z\cos(u)-\sin(u)(x\cos(v)+y\sin(v))] \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

with $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le u \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ latitude, $0 \le v < 2\pi$ longitude and $0 \le w < 2\pi$ vertical direction.

---

In particular, wanting to simulate everything in `Mathematica`, we have:

```
{r, R, H} = {1, 4, 10};

s = Flatten[Table[{x -> R Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ], y -> R Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], z -> R Cos[ϕ]},
                  {ϕ, 0, π, π/100.}, {θ, 0, 2π, 2π/100.}], 1];
c = Flatten[Table[{x -> r Cos[θ], y -> r Sin[θ], z -> t},
                  {t, R, H, (H - R)/100.}, {θ, 0, 2π, 2π/100.}], 1];
p = Flatten[Table[{x -> ρ Cos[θ], y -> ρ Sin[θ], z -> H},
                  {ρ, 0, r, r/100.}, {θ, 0, 2π, 2π/100.}], 1];

Manipulate[
 f = {Cos[w] (y Cos[v] - x Sin[v]) - Sin[w] (z Cos[u] - Sin[u] (x Cos[v] + y Sin[v])),
      Sin[w] (y Cos[v] - x Sin[v]) + Cos[w] (z Cos[u] - Sin[u] (x Cos[v] + y Sin[v]))};
 Graphics[{Blue, Point[f /. s], Red, Point[f /. c], Green, Point[f /. p]},
           Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x'", "y'"}, PlotRange -> {{-H, H}, {-H, H}}],
 {{u, -π/4}, -π/2, π/2}, {{v, 0}, 0, 2π}, {{w, π/2}, 0, 2π}]
```

[image]

where $u=-\frac{\pi}{4}$, $v=0$, $w=\frac{\pi}{2}$ having been fixed, the *orthographic projection* simplifies to:

$$
x' = -\frac{x+z}{\sqrt{2}},
\quad \quad \quad
y' = y
$$

and on the basis of these relations the distance you request is equal to $\boxed{d=\frac{R-r}{\sqrt{2}}}$.